# Positioning an element in the top right corner of the parent element and ensuring wrapping around it

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to create a container for an arbitrary number of elements, with an expand/collapse button. The button should be in the top right corner of the container, and the elements inside the container should wrap around the button. Here's the idea:

[image]

I made a quick [Codepen prototype](http://codepen.io/azangru/pen/mAjkGX) of this element, but the only way I could come up with to position the button in the top right corner was `float: right`:

html:

```
<div class="container closed">
  <button>Click</button>
  <!-- some divs with class "child" inserted with js -->
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  height: 80px;
  width: 330px;
  margin: auto;
}

button {
  float: right;
  margin: 1.3em 1.6em 0 0;
}

.closed {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

So this seems to work with `float: right` but floats are so passé :-) Is there a cleaner way of positioning the button? I thought flexbox would be able to do it, but couldn't figure out a way of achieving this with flexbox. Any advice?

**UPD:** Added the relevant html and css code.

Comment: Will there always be four items per row, or is that variable?

Comment: @Michael_B It's variable.

Comment: I think the float method is a good idea. Floats may be "passé" for overall layout purposes. But in this case, I think it's being used properly. After all, the whole idea of floats is to allow text (inline content) to wrap around images (content removed from the normal flow and fixed to the right or left).

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this purely with CSS, if you use the `flex` property of CSS3's flexbox, just like you said. I made a small demo to prove the point.

The core part in CSS lies here:

```css
display: flex;
flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
```

The `display: flex` will stretch the content across the width available and the `row-reverse` will align the items from right-to-left (where LTR is default). Read more [about flexbox at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

The other part is the toggle of the height of the menu, I don't know how many items you (can) have, but in the demo I used a bit of vanilla JavaScript to expand and collapse the menu.

```js
var mainNav = document.getElementById('menu-list');
var navToggle = document.getElementById('expandbutton');

function mainNavToggle() {
  mainNav.classList.toggle('expanded');
}

navToggle.addEventListener('click', mainNavToggle);
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 60px;
}

.list,
.list-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-item {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  background-color: teal;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top-right {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}

.list.expanded {
  height: 100px;
}

.list > .list-item:nth-last-child(n+4) ~ .list-button {
  order: 1;
}

.list > .list-item:nth-child(n+4) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list" id="menu-list">
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="btn">Button</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="btn">Button</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="btn">Button</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="btn">Button</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="btn">Button</a></li>
    <li class="list-item"><a href="#" class="btn">Button</a></li>
    <li class="list-item list-button">
      <button href="#" id="expandbutton" class="btn top-right">Expand</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I updated the snippet with the `flexbox` property of `order` which really helps in this case ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)).

```css
.list > .list-item:nth-last-child(n+4) ~ .list-button {
  order: 1;
}

.list > .list-item:nth-child(n+4) {
  order: 2;
}
```

The initial value of `order` is `0`. If you want to move the order around, it has to be higher than the initial value, so that's why we need to set the item of `.list-button` to `order: 1`. All the elements *after* the button needs to get behind or under the button (in case of 4 elements per row), so the `:nth-child(n+4)` needs an `order: 2`. See the updated snippet for a small demo.

Comment: Thank you for the example! But the bottom row of buttons in your example looks unusual (which wouldn’t work for me): it aligns to the right edge of the container (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/HjKT1UV.png), while one would normally expect the incomplete row of items to align left.

Comment: Thanks again! There is an assumption you are making that there are only 4 items in a row, while the number of items (or their width) in my case are arbitrary. But since I haven't made that clear in my original question, I will accept your answer. And thanks again for teaching me some flexbox :-)